# Experience editor, error when adding new component 'Could not find the rendering in the HTML loaded from server'

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, components

In Experience editor, the following error appears in the F12 Console when adding a new component with any rendering: 'Could not find the rendering in the HTML loaded from server'. I am logged in as admin/b.

Answer (score 2):

1. Find out the name of the placeholder that you are inserting into by hovering the mouse over the "Add here" button.
2. Let's assume it is the 'content' placeholder, go to Content Editor > navigate to content (/sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings/content),
3. Go to the "Data" section, "Allowed Controls", click Edit and then add the desired rendering (or all of them which is not recommended).
4. Save. Error should be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

For reference we were experiencing the same error and found that it was caused by having a Controller HTTP Post action with the same name as the view (when using SXA). Changing the action name resolved our issue.